# Prove that $B$ is a subfield of $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

If a subring $B$ of a field $F$ is closed with respect to multiplicative inverses, then $B$ is a field.

---

Fields are commutative rings with unity, and every nonzero element has an inverse.
A subring is closed with respect to addition, multiplication, and negatives.

So $B$ is a subring that's also closed with respect to multiplicative inverses... To show that it's a field, don't I need to show that it's closed with respect to additive inverses? I'm really not sure what to do

Comment: I know. But that doesn't mean it's necessarily a field?

Comment: If $B$ is a (sub)ring, it’s closed under $+$, $-$, and $\cdot$.

Comment: So that implies that it is closed with respect to additive inverses? ...since $a, -a \in B$, $a+(-a)=a-a=0$? So $-a$ is the additive inverse for $a$?

Comment: What does being "closed wrt multiplicative inverses" mean? Does this mean that any non zero element in $\;B\;$ has an inverse in $\;B\;$ ? Because this much is all that needs to be proved in order to get a field, as $\;B\;$ is already an integral domain...

Comment: Yes, being closed under subtraction is the *same* as having additive inverses. Can you see that? Maybe you didn’t catch on that “additive inverses” and “negatives” are just different words for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is a subring, $B$ is a ring.  Also, since multiplication in $F$ is commutative, multiplication in $B$ is commutative.  So $B$ is a commutative ring.
Finally, you just need to show every nonzero element of $B$ has a multiplicative inverse in $B$, and $B$ will be a field.